# Отсутвие задержки при вызове setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Функция`scheduleUpdatesInRedis()` назначает обновления. Для этого, она вызывает функцию `performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis()`, рекурсивно вызывающую себя спустя время, расчитываемое функцией `getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate()`.

Если я понимаю правильно, я в качестве первого параметра `setTimeout()` передаю именно анонимную функцию, а не результат ее выполнения, следовательно, задержка быть должна, так как в стандартном потоке вывода значения `getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate()` всегда большие.

Исходные коды функций:

```
scheduleRanksUpdates : () => {
    console.info(`Updates of ranks in redis have been scheduled`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        return performScheduledRanksUpdatesInRedis(); // It will be called infinitely unless interrupted
    }, getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate());
}
```

И

```
function performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis(index, url, fn = null) {
    //updateDataInRedis(index, url, fn);
    console.info(getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate());
    setTimeout(function () {
        return performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis(index, url, fn);
    }, getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate());
}
```

Вывод:

> performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis(index, url, fn);
>   31518656000
>   31518656000
>   31518656000
>   31518656000
>   31518656000
>   31518656000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000
>   31518655000

Comment: Что значат эти цифры? Вы хотите отложить исполнение функции на 31518656 секунд, то есть на год?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values

Answer (score 0):

В посте до редакции был приведен исходный код другой функции. Исходный код `scheduleUpdatesInRedis()`:

```
scheduleUpdatesInRedis :  (index, url, fn = null) => {
    console.info(`Updates of ${index} [${url}] in redis have been scheduled`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.info('performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis(index, url, fn);');
        return performScheduledUpdateOfDataInRedis(index, url, fn); // It will be called infinitely unless interrupted
    }, getTimeLeftBeforeUpdate());
}
```

Comment: Пришлось написать так, так как комментарии запрещены пока не будет 50 репутации. Отложить исполнение функции требуется примерно на неделю.

Comment: в неделе примерно 600 000 секунд

Comment: Время передаваемое в setTimeout, согласно https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval, должно быть в миллисекундах, а не секундах.

Comment: в неделе примерно 600 000 000 миллисекунд

Comment: Временной промежуток, вычисляемый данной функцией, не так важен, если setTimeout() может работать с ним.

Comment: не надо уходить от вопроса ). Вы надеетесь, что Ваша программа проработает год и дождется события таймаута?

Comment: Я сейчас проверю, не является ли проблемой слишком большое значение первой переменной.

Comment: я не уловил Вашу нумерацию переменных. Какая из них первая?

Comment: Первая переменная передаваемая как аргумент в setTimeout()

Comment: Поправочка, второй аргумент (задержка). У меня только 8 утра

Comment: Ошибка с количество миллисекунд в неделе произошла из-за этого сайта, который оказался в топ-3 поисковика: https://kalkulator.pro/week-to-millisecond.html

Comment: Естественно, это и является причиной моментального вызова. Там ограничение 2^31. Я дал ссылку под вопросом.

Comment: Видимо я совсем зажрался с int64 и длинной арифметикой python. Большое спасибо за помощь